# Convert ruby regular expression definition to python regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I've following regexes defined for capturing the gem names in a Gemfile.

```
GEM_NAME = /[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+/

QUOTED_GEM_NAME = /(?:(?<gq>["'])(?<name>#{GEM_NAME})\k<gq>|%q<(?<name>#{GEM_NAME})>)/
```

I want to convert these into a regex that can be used in python and other languages.

I tried `(?:(["'])([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+)\k["']|%q<([a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+)>)` based on substitution and several similar combinations but none of them worked. Here's the regexr link http://regexr.com/3g527

Can someone please explain what should be correct process for converting these ruby regular expression defintions into a form that can be used by python.

Comment: Python `re` can't handle identically named groups in  1 regex. Also, to define a named group, you need to use `(?P<name>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a named group, you need to use `(?P<name>)` and then `(?p=name)` named 
If you can afford a 3rd party library, you may use PyPi regex module and use the approach you had in Ruby (as `regex` supports multiple identically named capturing groups):

```
s = """%q<Some-name1> "some-name2" 'some-name3'"""

GEM_NAME = r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+'
QUOTED_GEM_NAME = r'(?:(?P<gq>["\'])(?<name>{0})(?P=gq)|%q<(?P<name>{0})>)'.format(GEM_NAME)
print(QUOTED_GEM_NAME)
# => # (?:(?P<gq>["\'])(?<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)(?P=gq)|%q<(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)>)

import regex
res = [x.group("name") for x in regex.finditer(QUOTED_GEM_NAME, s)]
print(res)
# => ['Some-name1', 'some-name2', 'some-name3']
```

backreference in the replacement pattern.

See [this Python demo](http://rextester.com/IHM83801).

If you decide to go with Python `re`, it can't handle identically named groups in one regex pattern.

You can discard the named groups altogether and use numbered ones, and use `re.finditer` to iterate over all the matches with comprehension to grab the right capture.

[Example Python code](http://ideone.com/jWbTW3):

```
import re
GEM_NAME = r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+'
QUOTED_GEM_NAME = r"([\"'])({0})\1|%q<({0})>".format(GEM_NAME)
s = """%q<Some-name1> "some-name2" 'some-name3'"""
matches = [x.group(2) if x.group(1) else x.group(3) for x in re.finditer(QUOTED_GEM_NAME, s)]
print(matches)
# => ['Some-name1', 'some-name2', 'some-name3']
```

So, `([\"'])({0})\1|%q<({0})>` has got 3 capturing groups: if Group 1 matches, the first alternative got matched, thus, Group 2 is taken, else, the second alternative matched, and Group 3 value is grabbed in the comprehension.

**Pattern details**

- `([\"'])` - Group 1: a `"` or `'`
- `({0})` - Group 2: `GEM_NAME` pattern
- `\1` - inline backreference to the Group 1 captured value (note that `r'...'` raw string literal allows using a single backslash to define a backreference in the string literal)
- `|` - or
- `%q<` - a literal substring
- `({0})` - Group 3: `GEM_NAME` pattern
- `>` - a literal `>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your pattern like this:

```
GEM_NAME = r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+'

QUOTED_GEM_NAME = r'''["'%] # first possible character
    (?:(?<=%)q<)? # if preceded by a % match "q<"
    (?P<name> # the three possibilities excluding the delimiters
        (?<=") {0} (?=") |
        (?<=') {0} (?=') |
        (?<=<) {0} (?=>)
    )
    ["'>] #'"# closing delimiter
    (?x) # switch the verbose mode on for all the pattern
'''.format(GEM_NAME)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/VeyBuk/1)

Advantages:

- the pattern doesn't start with an alternation that makes the search slow. *(the alternation here is only tested at interesting positions after a quote or a %, when your version tests each branch of the alternation for each position in the string)*. This optimisation technique is called "the first character discrimination" and consists to quickly discard useless positions in a string.
- you need only one capture group occurrence (quotes and angle brackets are excluded from it and only tested with lookarounds). This way you can use `re.findall` to get a list of gems without further manipulation.
- the gq group wasn't useful and was removed (shorten a pattern at the cost of creating a useless capture group isn't a good idea)

Note that you don't need to escape the dot inside a character class.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use a conditional and consolidate the name.

`(?:(?:(["'])|%q<)(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+)(?(1)\1|>))`

Expanded

```
 (?:
      (?:                           # Delimiters
           ( ["'] )                      # (1), ' or "
        |                              # or,
           %q<                           # %q
      )
      (?P<name> [a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+ ) # (2), Name
      (?(1) \1 | > )                # Did group 1 match ? match it here, else >
 )
```

Python

```
import re

s = ' "asdf"  %q<asdfasdf>  '

print ( re.findall( r'(?:(?:(["\'])|%q<)(?P<name>[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\.]+)(?(1)\1|>))', s ) )
```

Output

```
[('"', 'asdf'), ('', 'asdfasdf')]
```